# Converting a character array which includes asterisks into a numeric in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, double, character

I am struggling to convert character arrays containing asterisks ('*') into numeric doubles.

I have a cell array of character vectors based on data imported from a .dat file. For example, the cell array `C` contains a column of cells (e.g., `C{1,1}, C{2,1}, ... C{n,1}`), each of which containing a character vector, e.g., `C{1,1}` contains:

```
'23.000          *          *      1.000      1.000      1.000     34.000      5.065      6.719'
```

When I try to convert `C{1,1}` to a numeric double, MATLAB returns an empty double, e.g.,

```
new_double = str2num(C{1,1})

new_double =

     []
```

When I remove the asterisk manually, the code works:

```
 new_double = str2num(C{1,1})

 new_double =

   23.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000   34.0000    5.0650    6.7190
```

All I want to do is read the data into a double array for further processing. I don't care if the command ignores the asterisks or replaces them with NaNs - the data with asterisks are not important to me. What is important is that I read data from the last two columns, e.g., 5.065 6.71. Unfortunately, I cannot index them since they are embedded within a character vector.

I have also tried using:

```
c2 = C{1,1};
new_double = sscanf(c2,'%f%');
```

But it stops reading at the asterisk, e.g.,

```
new_double =

    23
```

I have searched far and wide, the only useful post being: https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/127847-how-to-read-csv-file-with-asterix However, I can't use this method because I am working from a character vector rather than delimited data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another way:

```
C{1,1} = '23.000          *          *      1.000      1.000      1.000     34.000      5.065      6.719';
result = str2double(strsplit(C{1}));
```

This gives

```
result =
   23.0000       NaN       NaN    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000   34.0000    5.0650    6.7190
```

This works as follows:

1. [`strsplit`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html) splits the string at spaces. This gives a cell array of substrings formed by contiguous non-space characterse;
2. [`str2double`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html) converts each of thsoe cells into a number, and gives a numeric vector as result, with `NaN` at entries that cannot be interpreted as numbers.

An advantage of using `str2double` over `str2num` is that the former doesn't internally use `eval`, so it cannot run potentially dangerous code.

Comment: Clever. Certainly beats the regex approach. I didn't know `str2double` could do that.

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks! Using a regex is a nice approach too

Comment: Thank you both for your informative and speedy responses. I learned a 
 lot from both. Time to spread the word about 'strsplit'!!

Answer (score 2):

Let's do both.  For the first case where you want to ignore the asterisks, you can remove them from the string and perform `str2num` as normal.  Defining your data:

```
C{1,1} = '23.000          *          *      1.000      1.000      1.000     34.000      5.065      6.719';
```

... you can use [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to potentially remove multiple asterisks that are in sequence (like if you had `**`, `***`, etc.) and change them to the empty string with [`regexprep`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html):

```
out = regexprep(C, '*+', '');
```

What this says is that for all strings in your cell array `C`, we replace any existing sequence of `*` with the empty string.

In this case, we get:

```
>> out = regexprep(C, '*+', '')

out =

  cell

    '23.000                          1.000      1.000      1.000     34.000      5.065      6.719'
```

You can go ahead and invoke `str2num` accordingly.  Should you decide to replace the asterisks with `NaN` for example, just use `regexprep` again but specify `NaN` instead of the blank string:

```
out = regexprep(C, '*+', 'NaN');
```

We get:

```
>> out = regexprep(C, '*+', 'NaN');

out =

  cell

    '23.000          NaN          NaN      1.000      1.000      1.000     34.000      5.065      6.719'
```

The point is to replace the affected parts of your string with something else, and `regexprep` can certainly help.